# Стирается файл json в on_message. discord.py

Tags: json, discord, бот, discord.py

я хочу написать систему уровней для своего бота discord. По плану бот должен после каждого сообщения участника добавлять некоторое кол-во XP. Однако после того, как я прописываю условие, у меня стирается файл users.json. Я не могу понять в чем у меня ошибка и почему код не работает так, как надо.

````
poc = ["23934", "93842040281", "9300438508"]

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    message.content = message.content.lower()
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    for i in range(0, len(poc)):
      if poc[i] not in message.content.lower():
        with open("users.json", "r") as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            file.close()
        with open("users.json", "w") as file:
            data[str(message.author.id)]["xp"] += 1
            data[str(message.author.id)]["messages"] += 1
            json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
            file.close()
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            if data[str(message.author.id)]["xp"] >= 40:
            file.close()
              with open("users.json", "w") as file:
                data[str(message.author.id)]["xp"] = 0
                data[str(message.author.id)]["lvl"] += 1
                json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
                file.close()
                await message.channel.send(embed=Embed(description=f'Поздравляю, {message.author.mention}, ты повысил свой уровень до {data[str(message.author.id)]["lvl"]}'))```


Ошибка выглядит так:

Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/SweetyHouseBot02624632476348/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 351, in on_message
    data[str(message.author.id)]["stat"] += 1
KeyError: '981583703518093386'
````

Answer (score 0):

`file.open(filePath, param)` где param - это параметры открытия файлов. Если вы обратитесь к документации то вы увидите, что параметр 'w' создаёт новый файл для записи (или если он имеется затирает всё его содержимое).
Если вам надо только прочитать файл используйте параметр 'r':

```py
with open("users.json", "r") as file:
  ...
```

Comment: Нет, мне нужно конкретно открыть файл на запись, чтобы сохранить изменения! Посмотрите мой код еще раз. Я добавил туда сообщение об ошибке